# Regex for checking the string is not email

Tags: regex

I have this regex to check if the input string is email address.

```
/^.+@.+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/
```

Want to find the regex to check if the input string is not the email.  Need help

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think a negative lookahead would be more appropriate `/^(?!.+@.+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$)/`

Comment: Sure, that is what I meant :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this [A-Za-z0-9_]+(?=[\s.,])

Comment: Your welcome ;) if it is correct please sign it as an answer